# Missing Cygint-2.dll error in Putty

Tags: dll, cygwin, putty

I am using Putty, not Cygwin. I am trying for a password less connection to the server. I created a public and private key. When I try to give permission to the folder, I get the following message:

```
$chmod 700 $Home /Users/Name/.ssh 
the program cannot start because cygintl-2.dll is missing
```

How should I give permission to the folder and file for password-less automatic authentication?

Do I require this functionality? I have mixed up my knowledge of putty and cygwin.
I found cygwin quite complex to set up, and am afraid of damaging my system.
Putty seems simple though lacks functionality (i.e. ease of use).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, i was in hurry so could not mange to write good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PuTTY merely offers the client side of the SSH connection. It doesn't process commands like `chmod`: it simply accepts your keystrokes inputting that command and sends them to the server side, which processes them and sends the output back through the SSH channel to the SSH client, which is PuTTY in this case.

Apparently your SSH server is the Cygwin one, and you have somehow broken your Cygwin installation. In the Cygwin `setup.exe`, go through the setup sequence until you get to the "Select Packages" screen, then type "intl" in the Search box. Open the Libs section, and click the third column on the "libintl2" line until it says Reinstall. Proceed.

That should fix this one particular problem, but chances are good that if you've lost that one library, you've broken other things, too. A complete Cygwin reinstallation might be in order.

Comment: Or, given that the OP is conflating PuTTY and Cygwin, I'd recommend a complete Cygwin *un*installation. With only PuTTY installed, there's no chance of misusing and abusing Cygwin commands.

Comment: mount is not recognised, cygwin is not recognized, it must be that just puty is installed since ssh is recognized, as well as scp is recognized.

Comment: mount is not recognised, cygwin is not recognized, it must be that just puty is installed since ssh is recognized, as well as scp is recognized.    CYGWIN_SYSLOG is present in the C drive, along with settings, and user, all in C drive. I do have putty folder as well in C drive, containing putty as application. how do you suggest I shall i proceed ahead in uninstalling all of it.

Comment: looking at the environment variables i can see CYGWIN tty present there if it helps, to identify the issue.

Comment: finally now i have installed a complete cygwin, now seems its working with all commands. which means there was no cygwin installed.

Comment: @warren Young thanks to you, now am able to login password less.  and thanks for the edit as well dawan

Comment: @casperOne thanks for discouraging to use stackoverflow.